# Running a method on screen startup

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Let me try and explain this. Within a project folder has .m and .h files (we all know that haha) however when you start a new ".m" with a xib like for example:

```
ViewTwoController *loginView = [[ViewTwoController alloc] initWithNibName:@"contentscreen" bundle:nil];
[self presentModalViewController:loginView animated:YES];
[loginView release];
```

I was wondering how do I create a method that runs as soon as that class (if I can call it that, I'm new to objective C) similar to a main method that Java would have. I want to run some code as soon as that .m has been called and started. Any help would be valued thanks :)

Comment: I guess what you're trying to find is `-(void)viewDidLoad` method. If your class inherits UIViewController then this method will appear by default. You don't need to define it explicitly.

Comment: Please give a brief look on this, that would be very helpful in starting label.. http://adeem.me/blog/2009/07/03/beignner-iphone-sdk-hello-world-tutorial-first-application/

Comment: Yup, I just tried that and it seems to be working. Brilliant. I'm starting to get an understanding of the basics of Objective C, however I'll take Java anyway lol. The noob that I am.

Comment: Yeah, its a lot different from Java once you move on. But if you spend more time with Objective C, you'll find its equally interesting as Java.

Comment: Definitely interesting, however the problem I have with SQLite is frustrating the hell out of me. It was easy on Android!

Comment: I agree to that point of yours. It can get a bit troubling initially. Even I had a tough time getting through it. If you've any problem in that, you can ask me about that. I'd try my best to solve it for you.

Comment: Legend. I might just do that. How can I contact you?

Comment: Visit me in chat room for iPhone/iPad I am available there everyday. Or send me your problem as an email. My email address is mentioned in my profile.

Comment: Fantastic I shall do just that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be safe try to put this in `- (void)viewDidLoad`

Everything that happens here happens when the view is loaded onto the screen.

Note that there are number of places where you can put your method, in `viewWillAppear` or in your AppDelegate etc. But I found putting UI elements like your login popup better in `viewDidLoad`

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 1):

You can add additional code in `viewDidLoad` method, which is called as soon as your view controller has been loaded.

Using the `initWithNibName:bundle:` method, your view controller will be automatically loaded and initialized.